# Why won't my price show up on my products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I can't get the price of the products to show up on the page. Whenever I update the price, it seems like it doesn't save.

This is my migration file, in which I added a price (integer) to a product.

```
class AddPriceToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :products, :price, :integer
  end
end
```

Here is where I try to show the price:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= image_tag @product.image.url(:large) %>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @product.titel %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @product.beschrijving %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Price:</strong>
  <%= @product.price %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %>

<%= link_to 'Destroy', @product, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>

<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

I hope someone can help me fixing this problem,
Sincerely Arend

Comment: So many questions: Did you permit price through strong parameters? Have you run the migration file? Have you restarted the server? What have you tried? What is happening? Do the logs show anything?

Comment: Where do you update your price? probably you can't get it because it's nil, no 0, you need to add `, default: 0` to your migration if you want to use that default (You will need to reset the database if you already have runned the migration)

Comment: How are you updating the price? Are you sure it is working? Because in the view it seens that everything is OK.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you very much, it is solved now. I forgot to permit the price through parameters.

Comment: @HugoFarji Thank you for answering the question, I solved it already. I forgot to permit the price.

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata Thank you for answering the question, I solved it already. I forgot to permit the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved, thanks to engineersmnky. I forgot to permit the price through the parameters.

Here is how I required the parameters

```
def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :image)
    end
```

Comment: Could you expand? maybe later somebody has a similar problem, try adding the code where you forgot to put the parametter. It would be helpful for somebody later

Comment: It's worth adding the code here that fixed the problem rather than this *teaser* answer.